# Can I intercept form submit data to use with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, forms, django-forms

I have a Django app that shows a list of items in a selection item. When the user changes the selected item, I use AJAX to insert a form (using Django's Form and formset helpers) into a "content" section on the page to edit that item's data.

What I would like to do is, when the user clicks a "Save" button on the form, a Javascript function sends the POST data as though the form had been submitted, and then uses AJAX again to reinject the new data from the page.

I want to maintain a clean URL at all times, but always return to the entry you were editing (hence the AJAX HTML replacement).

I would prefer not to have to grab all the form fields and reconstruct a string that my Django Forms will recognize correctly.

Is there a way to do this? Am I going about the whole thing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To grab whole form and send it using AJAX on submit do something like this (assuming jQuery):

```
jQuery('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = jQuery(this);
    var data = form.serialize();

    jQuery.post(form.attr('action'), data, function(html) {
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: I haven't used jQuery before, but it looks pretty straightforward. I'll give that a shot and report back. Thanks!